# how to save foreach loop last value into variable

Tags: php, pdf-generation, foreach-loop-container

How can i store last value of `$total['value']` into `$COD`?

Variable and echo it and other place of page code is

```
 <?php foreach( $wpo_wcpdf->get_woocommerce_totals() as $key => $total ) : ?>
    <tr class="<?php echo $key; ?>">
        <td class="no-borders">&nbsp;</td>
        <th class="description"><?php echo $total['label']; ?></th>
        <td class="price"><span class="totals-price"><?php echo $total['value']; ?></span></td>
    </tr>   
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

This code of "WooCommerce PDF Invoices & Packing Slips" free plugin

Comment: `$COD = $total['value'];` ??

Comment: It should keep the last value after loop. Have you tried it?

Comment: i just wanna save last value of $total['value'] need to print last value in which Grand Total

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, values will get overwritten and ultimately you will have last value

```
$COD = $total['value'];
```

Answer (score 0):

I Solve it using this

> if ($key === 'order_total'){ $COD = $total['value']; }

```
<?php foreach( $wpo_wcpdf->get_woocommerce_totals($grand_total) as $key => $total ) : ?>
                    <tr class="<?php echo $key; ?>">
                        <td class="no-borders">&nbsp;</td> 
                        <th class="description"><?php echo $total['label']; ?></th>
                        <?php if ($key === 'order_total'){ $COD = $total['value']; } ?>

                        <td class="price"><span class="totals-price"><?php echo $total['value']; ?></span></td>
                    </tr>   
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Thanks @Zl3n
Thanks Stackoverflow